# How can I find out more about this device in my wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I am using a Netgear D6300 wifi modem router. Its DHCP server assigns IP in the range of 192.168.0.x

In its configuration utility, I spot this device:

[image]

It clearly does not receive a 192.168.0.x IP address.

How can I find out more about this device?

* The MAC address is fake because I am not sure if it is a good idea to expose this bit of information to the world

Comment: Just change the wifi password and see whether it is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by putting the real MAC address into a search tool such as www.coffer.com/mac_find/

This will help you find the vendor of the network card. That in turn may help you identify the device that contains it.

Some vendors such as Apple now give out random MAC addresses but they are still supposed to be within certain ranges so the lookup should still give you a clue.

You can also run something like the SoftPerfect Network Scanner to try to discover more information about the device.

If you are sure it isn't one of yours, you should be able to use the MAC filtering features of your router or access point to prevent that device appearing on your network. You might also want to review the complexity of your Wi-Fi password to prevent unwanted intrusions.

The IP address given is an internally allocated one. That is to say that it is normally assigned when a machine cannot obtain an address. The range 169.254.0.0/16 is reserved for that purpose. In this case, it may have appeared because something has connected to your Wi-Fi but not managed to (or has chosen not to) listen to DHCP for an address. The address range should not be routeable and therefore should not present a threat to your network though of course, it is better to be safe that sorry.